# Kubectl unable to connect to server after creation on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, amazon-eks

I was following the AWS guide on setting up a cluster on EKS, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-cluster.html). I got all the way to step 4. However, when trying:

```
kubectl get svc
```

I get the following error message:

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [IP:Port]: i/o timeout

I assume this has something to do with my kubeconfig not being correct. My config looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: [SERVER_URL]
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:[ACCT_ID]:cluster/[CLUSTER_NAME]
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:[ACCT_ID]:cluster/[CLUSTER_NAME]
    user: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:[ACCT_ID]:cluster/[CLUSTER_NAME]
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:[ACCT_ID]:cluster/[CLUSTER_NAME]
current-context: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:[ACCT_ID]:cluster/[CLUSTER_NAME]
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:[ACCT_ID]:cluster/[CLUSTER_NAME]
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - ap-southeast-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - [CLUSTER_NAME]
      command: aws
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: default
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false
```

I thought it might be related to my force-MFA policy so I removed that. Also, when I tried to do `aws eks describe-cluster --name [CLUSTER_NAME] --profile default`, I got this result:

```
{
    "cluster": {
        "name": "[CLUSTER_NAME]",
        "arn": "arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:[ACCT_ID]:cluster/quantum-dev",
        "createdAt": "2023-01-12T14:43:44.672000+09:00",
        "version": "1.24",
        "endpoint": "https://[CLUSTER_ID].gr7.ap-southeast-1.eks.amazonaws.com",
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::[ACCT_ID]:role/[CLUSTER_NAME]-cluster-role",
        "resourcesVpcConfig": {
            "subnetIds": [
                "subnet-0d6f0f95e19b421ab",
                "subnet-0dfaf09d4f3f1bf71",
                "subnet-0b59c6e7719981e06"
            ],
            "securityGroupIds": [
                "sg-01bc18956704de609"
            ],
            "clusterSecurityGroupId": "sg-09a22a6ea091c7a4d",
            "vpcId": "vpc-0e1db1e6fb8d7711c",
            "endpointPublicAccess": false,
            "endpointPrivateAccess": true,
            "publicAccessCidrs": []
        },
        "kubernetesNetworkConfig": {
            "serviceIpv4Cidr": "10.100.0.0/16",
            "ipFamily": "ipv4"
        },
        "logging": {
            "clusterLogging": [
                {
                    "types": [
                        "api"
                    ],
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "audit",
                        "authenticator",
                        "controllerManager",
                        "scheduler"
                    ],
                    "enabled": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "identity": {
            "oidc": {
                "issuer": "https://oidc.eks.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/id/[CLUSTER_ID]"
            }
        },
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "certificateAuthority": {
            "data": "[CERTIFICATE]"
        },
        "platformVersion": "eks.3",
        "tags": {
            "Environment": "dev"
        },
        "encryptionConfig": [
            {
                "resources": [
                    "secrets"
                ],
                "provider": {
                    "keyArn": "arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-1:[ACCT_ID]:key/[KMS_KEY_ID]"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

which tells me that I have the `eks:DescribeCluster` permission. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

generate a aws eks kubeconfig file

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-generate-kubeconfig-file-for-cluster/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: I thought this might be the problem but, even after trying it, I'm still experiencing the same problem.